# How to decrease the Width and Height of CheckBox in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

Can anyone tell me how to reduce the width and height of CheckBox in order to display very small CheckBox in Android ?

Thanks In Advance,

Answer (score 1):

`setWidth(int)` and `setHeight(int)` since `CheckBox` extends `CompoundButton` which extends `Button`

Try referring to [this tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=17050)

Alernatively try changing it via the XML:

```
<CheckBox 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="new checkbox" 
    android:background="@drawable/my_checkbox_background"
    android:button="@drawable/my_checkbox" />
```

Comment: I created CheckBox through code and used setWidth() and setHeight() methods,but still the width and Height is not changed. Any other solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use setWidth(w) and setHeight(h) functions as you would for a normal Button.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: this only works from API 17 onwards...

---

As per my answer on this question:
 - [how can we reduce the size of checkbox please give me an idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13760524/383414)

---

`CheckBox` derives its height from the TEXT as well as the image.

Set these properties in your XML:

```
android:text=""
android:textSize="0sp"
```

Of course this only works if you want no text (worked for me).

Without these changes, the `CheckBox` was giving me a big margin around my image, as mentioned by Joe