# how can we reduce the size of checkbox please give me an idea

Tags: android, android-checkbox

How can we reduce the size of checkbox? Please give me an idea.

Comment: try this http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_change_look_of_checkbox-t4553.html

Answer (score 1):

You can define your owm state list drawable, to define different images for different states, as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--When checkbox is checked-->
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/img_checkbox_on" />
<!--When checkbox is not checked-->
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/img_checkbox_off" />
</selector>
```

and apply this selector to check box in xml by:

```
<CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/my_custom_checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: this only works from API 17 onwards...

---

`CheckBox` derives its height from the TEXT as well as the image.

Set these properties in your XML:

```
android:text=""
android:textSize="0sp"
```

Of course this only works if you want no text (worked for me).

Without these changes, the `CheckBox` was giving me a big margin around my image, as mentioned by Joe Plante.

Answer (score 1):

Use 
android:scaleX="0.5"
android:scaleY="0.5"

1 is for 100% size
0.5 is for 50% 
0.4 is for 40%...

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the size of the checkbox by changing its layout_width & layout_height.

Comment: my frnd i know i cn do with width and height but whats the problem when i reduce the size of width and height it is cutting down the checkbox

Comment: shirpal defenately u r right if u get any solution pls give me solution

Comment: ok...i think we should make any xml file in that xml file we have to make two images of selected checkbox and unselected checkbox that way we can do...

Answer (score 0):

Everything is standard, put in layout xml:

```
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/myCheckBoxId"
              android:checked="false"
              android:text="Check It!" 
              android:textSize="12"/> <!--look here --/>
```

Comment: That reduces the *text* attached to the checkbox, not the checkbox itself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a different issue. I had a checkbox separate from the text

I did the `drawable` bit and it didn't work for me. For me, I had a `drawable` and the checkbox height was stubbornly at a set height, so no matter what, there was space around it. So, I, at first, used m `layout_marginTop` and `layout_marginBottom` to negative values, like -15 dip. I admit that it feels like a hack, but it almost worked. The other way was setting the `layout_height="20dip"` which worked better.

Edit: this requires a layout that has `setable` margins like Linear and Relative

Answer (score 0):

You can just use scaleX and scaleY properies:

```
<CheckBox
 android:id="@+id/check_box"            
 android:scaleX="2.5"
 android:scaleY="2.5"/>
```

Comment: I realise that this is an old answer. I tried this and while it initially works, as soon as I click on the checkboxes they shrink back to the default 1.0 size.