# How to reduce the check box size in android?

Tags: android

I created a check box programmatically and it shows well. Is there any option to reduce check box width and height?

Comment: check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914707/how-to-decrease-the-width-and-height-of-checkbox-in-android

Comment: i create the check box programmatically

Answer (score -1):

Try following ::

```
CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox(this);
chkBox.setId(++myid);

//  AS  FOLLOWING, YOU SET SIZE
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams chkBoxParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //      OR    int  width,  int hieght);

chkBox.setLayoutParams(chkBoxParams);
chkBox.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
chkBox.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
//chkBox.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15);
chkBox.setText("Scroll Test");
Your_Main_View_Holder_Layout.addView(chkBox);
```

Comment: :your code for layoutparams just fix the size only,give the value of 20 in chkBoxParams then test it, but wat i want is the box size should decrease in set level

Comment: What do you mean by decrease in level??

Comment: if i give the value 20 my check box size should reduce,, if i give 10 my check box size should reduce half size of 20